# How to change text in RoR config file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix, sed

I have the following lines in config/application.rb file of a RoR project:

```
 [other lines that i omitted here]
 config.app_type= :rewards # :classic / :rewards
 config.app_prefix= '' # '$ ' for :classic  / '' for :rewards
 config.app_suffix= ' pts' # ' MXN', ' USD' for :classic / ' pts' for :rewards
```

I would like to change the text with a script using sed, to this:

```
 [other lines that i omitted here]
 config.app_type= :classic # :classic / :rewards
 config.app_prefix= '$ ' # '$ ' for :classic  / '' for :rewards
 config.app_suffix= ' USD' # ' MXN', ' USD' for :classic / ' pts' for :rewards
```

How can i do this with sed?, i still don't get it with regular expressions and sed yet... :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Using a file for the `sed` commands avoids the mess of escaping quotes.

Content of `script.sed`:

```
s/^\( *config\.app_type= *:\)rewards/\1classic/
s/^\( *config\.app_prefix= *\)''/\1'$ '/
s/^\( *config\.app_suffix= *\)' pts'/\1' USD'/
```

Run it like:

```
sed -f script.sed infile
```

With following output:

```
[other lines that i omitted here]
config.app_type= :classic # :classic / :rewards
config.app_prefix= '' # '$ ' for :classic  / '' for :rewards
config.app_suffix= ' pts' # ' MXN', ' USD' for :classic / ' pts' for :rewards
```

Comment: Mmmm.... For my particular case, I can only use custom bash files... What about using the escaping quotes?

Comment: @ianenri: What do you mean with *custom bash files*? You can run it directly from command-line using double-quotes, but then you must be more careful with variable interpolation (perhaps not here but in more complex commands), like: `sed -e "s/^\( *config\.app_type= *:\)rewards/\1classic/; ..." infile`